# Counting lines in a file matching specific string

Tags: bash, shell, awk, solaris

Suppose I have more than 3000 files `file.gz` with many lines like below. The fields are separated by commas. I want to count only the line in which the 21st field has today's date (ex:`20171101`).

I tried this:

```
awk -F',' '{if { $21 ~ "TZ=GMT+30 date '+%d-%m-%y'" } { ++count; } END { print count; }}' file.txt
```

but it's not working.

Comment: sorry. suppose with date '+%d-%m-%y'. But not working.

Comment: The 21st field is `20161226024317+0600` and your format would produce the date with hyphens.

Comment: Actually i have more then 3000 files and I have to count the line matching the date. All the files are in file.gz format. Not working actually. :(

Comment: @KaziNymulHaqueKanon: you cannot change the requirement after people have posted answers, and your question is no way comprehensible. Are there 3000 `.gz` files or 3000 `.txt` files inside each `.gz` file

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`, something like below

```
awk -F"," -v toSearch="$(date '+%Y%m%d')"  '$21 ~ toSearch{count++}END{print count}' file
```

The `date '+%Y%m%d'` produces the date in the format as you requested, e.g. `20170111`. Then matching that pattern on the `21st` field and counting the occurrence and printing it in the `END` clause.

Am not sure the `Solaris` version of `grep` supports the `-c` flag for counting the number of pattern matches, if so you can do it as

```
grep -c "$(date '+%Y%m%d')" file
```

Comment: If I use awk or nawk(as my server is solaris) it takes more time. Can I do the same with grep?

Comment: @KaziNymulHaqueKanon: Refer my update, use it as in my update, if `-c` flag is supported.

Comment: `$21 ~ "^" toSearch` instead of `$21 ~ toSearch` better

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM.: Thanks for the clarification Jose, I haven't  such a pattern before, care to explain how it works? Thanks!

Comment: Actually i have more then 3000 files and I have to count the line matching the date. All the files are in file.gz format. Not working actually. :(

Comment: @KaziNymulHaqueKanon: How do you expect it to work on a `.gz` file? Your initial question and this are totally different.

Comment: grep is faster because it doesn't do what you want (just look at the 21st field).Just use awk - it does what you asked for and the time difference will be absolutely negligible compared to using grep to do something other than what you want.

Comment: btw depending on your data which you haven't shown us yet, you might just need `$21 == toSearch` instead of a regexp comparison.

Comment: @EdMorton: This is a classic case of asking two questions in one, as soon as the first part was answered, OP flipped the question totally to a different one!

Comment: Yup and hasn't provided any sample input and expected output yet which is why some of us haven't attempted an answer yet :-). I've really given up answering questions that don't have sample input and expected output as at least half the time I guess wrong at what they want!

Comment: @EdMorton - there *was* sample input, but the OP edited it out of the question. :-P

Comment: @ghoti Reminds me of the movie Airplane when when in the control tower they're discussing turning on the search lights at the airport to help guide the plane in and Kramer (Robert Stack) says ["No, that's just what they'll be expecting us to do."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y0X0ZYbnHxA).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `gnu-grep`

```
grep -Ec "([^,]*,){20}$(date '+%Y%m%d')" file
```

**explanation:** `([^,]*,){20}` means 20 fields before the date to be checked

Answer (score 1):

Using awk and process substitution to uncompress a bunch of gzs and feed them to awk for analyzing and counting:

```
$ awk -F\, 'substr($21,1,8)==strftime("%Y%m%d"){i++}; END{print i}' * <(zcat *gz)
```

Explained:

```
substr($21,1,8) == strftime("%Y%m%d") {  # if the 8 first bytes of $21 match date
    i++                                  # increment counter
} 
END {                                    # in the end
    print i                              # output counter
}' * <(zcat *gz)                         # zcat all gzs to awk
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` and `cut` instead of `awk` and avoiding regular expressions:

```
cut -f21 -d, file | grep -Fc "$(date '+%Y%m%d')"
```

Comment: `gunzip` your file first and run the above command in a loop.

Comment: @EdMorton: added the `-F` flag to my answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If Perl is an option, this solution works on all 3000 gzipped files:

```
zcat *.gz | perl -F, -lane 'BEGIN{chomp($date=`date "+%Y%m%d"`); $count=0}; $count++ if $F[20] =~ /^$date/; END{print $count}'
```

These command-line options are used:

- `-l` removes newlines before processing, and adds them back in afterwards
- `-a` autosplit mode – split input lines into the `@F` array.  Defaults to splitting on whitespace.
- `-n` loop around each line of the input file
- `-e` execute the perl code
- `-F` autosplit modifier, in this case splits on `,`

`BEGIN{}` executes before the main loop.
The `$date` and `$count` variables are initialized.
The `$date` variable is set to the result of the shell command `date "+%Y%m%d"`

`$F[20]` is the 21st element in `@F`
If the 21st element starts with `$date`, increment `$count`

`END{}` executes after the main loop